# What rewards are available in Kingdom Hunters KvK?

Tags: lords-mobile

There are many guides and videos explaining how KvK works, but all seem to stop before any discussion of rewards.

I understand that at the kingdom level, those kingdoms that do well will receive gem loads for the following 24 hours that they can harvest.  However, there is also mention of guild points and solo points.  Are there rewards that each player earns for themselves, and that guilds can work towards together?  If so, how do rewards at that level work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experiencing my first KvK, I wanted to provide an overview for others wondering.

**Framework**

It looks like the 'hunters' part is just a modification to the classic KvK that gives double points for attacking a kingdom designated as your target, while your kingdom is designated as another kingdom's target.  Every few hours the targeting reverses.  These double points only appear to apply to wonders and kills; not monster hunting or gathering.

The KvK period appears as three separate events, and as Super S stated, any points earned apply to all three events:

**Solo War**

Solo war has three stages with rewards that resemble a solo or hell event.  The first two tier provided mediocre rewards, but the final tier provided extremely high value compared to solo or hell events.  In my particular case, at castle level 21, it included 6 each of some 15 different legendary monster boxes.

There are also rewards for your score vs other players within the same kingdom group (I'm guessing).  These rewards seemed mediocre; I reached rank 55 and received the equivalent of a tier 2 solo event reward.

Difficulty of the solo tiers was low; it required some 500k points to reach tier 3.  As I was only castle level 21 I relied on monster hunting and gathering.  The vast majority of my points came from gathering ore, which brought in some 5k points per minute with four armies out.  I would have had to kill several thousand troops per minute in attacks to match that, which hardly seemed worth it.  I was able to complete the tier 3 reward in under 3 hours.

**Guild War**

This part of the event worked similar to the solo war.  However, rewards at each level were special 'guild war chests'.  I do not know what these contained as my guild was not active enough to achieve one (if someone wants to comment with details I'll edit it into my answer).  There also appeared to be additional bonuses for guilds who place near the top when compared to other guilds in the kingdom group.

Tier 1 of the guild war rewards required some 4.5m points, so 9 players achieving their tier 3 solo rewards would earn a tier 1 guild reward.

**Kingdom War**

This appears to be a straight up comparison against the other three kingdoms in your kingdom group.  The winning kingdom gets high level gem loads; other get decreasing quality of gem loads.

Gem loads are gathering nodes that appear on the world map and can be gathered very quickly:

- Level 1 nodes contain 10 gems
- Level 2 nodes contain 50 gems
- Level 3 nodes contain 100 gems
- Level 4 nodes contain 200 gems
- Level 5 nodes contain 500 gems

We did not receive any larger nodes.  With four armies out at once and level 4 gem harvesting I could bring in some 15-20 gems per minute (6/minute while at node) while the nodes lasted.  In the first 50 minutes I mined almost 1000 gems, mostly from level 2 nodes, which was more than I had expected from the way people talk about these nodes.

**Tips**

You can take part and get sizable rewards even with a low level castle if you're willing to be active for a few hours during the event.

For solo rewards I advise a random relocator into a kingdom that you are not the target of.  Immediately 4-hour shield and then start sending out gathering armies.  Pull back any armies that are attacked; this probably won't happen often.  Within a few hours you'll have your solo rewards.

If your guild is active consider spending a little extra time gathering.  This also could boost your solo ranking giving you a little extra reward at the end.  Even if you can't take much part in KvK your guild could help earn you some rewards.

People tend to fight over the highest level gem lodes, so keep lower level ones in mind (ie: once level 3s show up, gather at 2s).  This doesn't slow you much as you'll usually spend less time enroute to level x-1 lodes; level xs are rarer and you'll go way further out to find an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

Points that **you** earn for your kingdom also go towards solo and guild rewards. Points that people from your guild earn go towards the guild KvK rewards as well, of course. The available rewards probably vary from KvK to KvK, but stay the same between each player and guild.

Comment: Thank you.  Are you able to expand on the rewards themselves at all?  Do they work in reward tiers, like guildfest?

Comment: No. There are no tiers. @Nicholas